# Cakephp Pagination with left right div combination

Tags: pagination, cakephp-2.0

I am working in a cakephp 2+ project. I am implementing pagination for sorting product listing in two left and right div combination. I am able to make left div but could not make right one since offset can not be set in pagination. I need half items in left div and half items in right div, so I can set limit but not able to offset. How can i do this?

```
Controller code

public function index()
{

$rows=$this->Product->find('count', array('conditions'=>array('Product.allow'=>1)));
if($rows%2==0) 
{
$this->paginate = array('conditions' => array('Product.allow'=>1,'limit'=>($rows/2));
$list_l = $this->paginate('Product');
$this->set('left_list',$list_l);
$this->paginate = array('conditions' => array('Product.allow'=>1,'limit'=>($rows/2), 'offset'=>$rows/2));
$list_r = $this->paginate('Product');
$this->set('right_list',$list_r);
} 
else 
{
$right_list=$this->Paginate('Product', array('Product.allow'=>1),array('limit'=>($rows-round($rows/2)), 'offset'=>round($rows/2)));
}
}

View Code

Foreach loop with array returned from controller
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not call `$this->paginate()` once and loop over all the items and perform the split in the View itself? Performing both calls is rather wasteful of database resources.

In that case you would have have a call to $this->paginate in the Controller. Say you want five items in the left column and five in the right:

```
$products = $this->paginate = array('conditions' => array('Product.allow'=>1, 'limit' => 10));
$this->set('products', $products);
```

In the view:

```
<div class="left-column">
<?php
  foreach ($products as $product) {
    debug($product);
    if ($count === 5) {
      echo "</div>\n<div class=\"right-column\">";
      $count = 1;
    }
    $count++;
  }
?>
</div>
```

Another way would be to use [`array_chunk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) in the Controller. Using this core PHP function you'll end up with multidimensional numerically indexed array which you can loop over and wrap the child arrays in their relevant divs.

```
<?php
  $limit = round(count($products)/2);
  $products = array_chunk($products, $limit);
  foreach ($products as $index=>$groupedProducts) {
    echo ($index === 0) ? '<div class="left-column">': '<div class="right-column">';
    foreach ($groupedProducts as $product) {
      debug($product);
    }
    echo '</div>';
  }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks mensch for your really precise reply. Im almost done...... Will put the code for future reference nearly......... Again thanks sorry cannot vote to you as my repu yet doesn't allow this ;)